# EF Core applies only one migration at a time

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, .net-6.0

I'm currently exploring the matter of running SQL Server Express for my integration tests as a docker container and ran into a strange issue: `DbContext.Database.Migrate()` would only apply one migration at a time.

**My Setup**

- Ancient MacBook Pro (2011), running macOS 10.14.6
- .NET 6.0 (6.0.201)
- EF Core with the SQL Server package (each 6.0.6)

**The issue**

I wrote some tests but currently, while evaluating my issue, I only ever run one of them via

```
dotnet test
```

from the terminal. My planned test setup was (basically)

- Spin up a new docker container
- Migrate
- Run the tests
- Remove the container

At the moment (for troubleshooting) I'm not removing the container, but keep it alive. My setup code is at the moment (made quite some changes to resolve my issue)

```cs
var docker = Process.Start("docker", "run -e \"ACCEPT_EULA=Y\" -e \"MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD=<password>\" -e \"MSSQL_PID=Express\" -p 60001:1433 --name sql_test -d mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest");
docker.WaitForExit();
_rawDbAccess.WaitForConnection(); // Waits until I can connect to the database successfully
_componentUnderTest.Database.Migrate();
```

Since I got strange errors that led me to think that not all migrations were applied, I investigated that matter and found out that this code actually did not applied all migrations on the new database, but only the oldest, meaning that my database is not migrated to the latest database until I ran the tests three times (since I do not removing the container anymore). I.e. my tests fail twice (since the database is not up to date) and then pass. Afaik `Migrate` should apply *all* migrations, not only the oldest one, right?

Things I tried to do to resolve my issue:

- Tried to call `Migrate` three times, once for each of my migrations
- Tried to call `Migrate` as long as `GetPendingMigrations()` yielded any migrations
- Switched to the latest SQL Server
- Tried to use `MigrateAsync` instead

I'm really irritated because this behavior is so different to what it's supposed to be. If migrating the DB failed I'd expect an Exception to be thrown and not to fail silently. And if it's not some kind of failure the behavior of `Migrate` is so different to what it is supposed to be.

Comment: Migrate applies all valid migrations, when one is incorrect from there one nothing is applied, but it fails. Maybe use dotnet-ef tool (dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef), manually create a fresh new db on sql docker instance, then dotnet ef database update see if fresh recreations stops in the same place without errors, if it does means either migrations are not correct referenced (generated), double check migration history table, maybe some keys were duplicated (usually duplicating existing migration .cs files) instead of using code first with CLI command (dotnet ef migrations add)

Comment: And if noting looks incorrect set breakpoint on each migration and designer .cs file from migration to determine what is incorrect, runt test with debug, then maybe is just unfortunate C# syntax